# Receive the error PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000] when trying to update some content text

Tags: nodes

I get the following error when I try to update a static page's content as an Administrator:

"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

In the logs, there is an error for type 'node' and type 'php':

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {pinit} (nid,
>   description, image, pincount) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 3
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   /sites/default/files/Steve155.jpg [:db_insert_placeholder_3] =>
>   horizontal ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7166 of
>   /home/diversif/public_html/includes/common.inc).

I just updated to the latest version of Drupal, and ran the update script on the database. I also created an authenticated user, and confirmed that they are experiencing the same issue.

I'm not modifying anything in the content other than some text. Are there other logs that I can look into to find the source of the problem, or the solution.?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error with the module

[pinit](https://drupal.org/project/pinit)

It's inserting a duplicate row for nid into it's database table.

It should probably use `db_merge` instead.

You may need to raise a bug report with the module maintainer.